# Getting unexpected colorized output on several commands

Tags: bash, colors, xterm

I just added this to my `.bashrc` to get colorized output with `less`:

```
# Colorize less man pages.
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\e[01;34m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\e[01;33m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\e[01;44;37m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\e[01;31m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_mr=$'\e[01;35m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\e[00m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\e[00m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\e[00m'
```

... and now all of a sudden certain commands (seems to be related to displaying environment variables) produce color output that matches these new settings. Am I escaping wrong? Or is this intentional behavior? I tried a few other escape variations, but they didn't work with `less`.

For example, here is a screenshot of an `env` command.

[image: env command]

`php -i` also has colorized output, but only on the environment variables section.

[image: php -i command]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal behavior. These environment variables contain escape sequences that cause the terminal to change its foreground color. You get the same visual effect when any program outputs them, be it `less` or `env`.

These variables need to contain the actual escape characters, less doesn't do any postprocessing on them.

Normally you can put less configuration variables in your [lesskey file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lesskey), but this doesn't work for the `LESS_TERMCAP_xx` variables, because less reads them before it reads the lesskey file (as of less 444). So you have no choice but to put them in the environment.

If you want these variables to apply only to `man` and not to other uses of `less`, you can use an alias for `man` that sets the `PAGER` variable to a wrapper script that sets the environment variables.

```
#!/bin/sh
escape=␛     # a literal escape character
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$escape'[01;34m'
…
exec less "$@"
```

(Alternatively, use `#!/bin/bash` on the first line and you can use the `#'\e'` syntax to get an escape character. On systems where `/bin/sh` is dash, using `/bin/sh` is very slightly faster, although it may not be noticeable in practice.)

Call this script `less-color`, and add `alias man='PAGER=less-color man'` to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`. On some systems, instead of creating an alias, you can tell `man` to use a different pager by setting the `MANPAGER` environment variable: `export MANPAGER=less-color` in your `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you've mistakenly set those LESS_* variables' values to strings that contain actual escape characters, as opposed to strings that contain a backslash followed by an e.  Thus every time you display those values, they change the color of your terminal.

I'd look very carefully at the settings you made in your .bashrc, and ensure they're correct.  I suspect that all you need to do is eliminate the dollar sign.

Comment: Removing the dollar sign messes up my man pages. For example, `man top` = `\e[01;34mSYNOPSIS\e[00m` instead of colorizing the word "SYNOPSIS".

Comment: The dollar sign didn't work. Can you think of a workaround? Maybe a way to restrict those LESS variables to only be used on man pages?

Answer (score 0):

As @Gilles points out in his answer, this is an expected behaviour.

Let me just add couple info.
`LESS_TERMCAP_xx` override TERMCAP capabilities. This overriding is managed by `less` itself in `screen.c` and the value is just used later on as if it was returned by TERMCAP library. That means it has to be raw sequence of control characters.

My account on how to "fix" this is to wrap `less` itself

```
$ cat ~/bin/less 
#!/bin/bash

# Start bold mode
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\e[1;37m'
# Start standout mode
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\e[1;37;41m'
# End standout mode
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\e[0m'
# Start underlining
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\e[4;93m'
# End underlining
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\e[0m'
# End all mode like so, us, mb, md and mr
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\e[0m'

exec /usr/bin/less "$@"
```

Comment: Funny, I am working on this right now and it's looking good. Do you have a version that also works with `#!/bin/sh` (which is dash, in my case)? I can't figure out how to insert a literal `ESC` character with vim.

Comment: @Jeff Just from top of my head you can always do something like `export LESS_TERMCAP_me="$(printf '\e[0m')"`. Actually if you look at @Gilles answer, he is claiming `export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$escape'[0m'` should work with `/bin/sh` too.